# C# create directory with 2 variables

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a directory using 2 variables (ctidSelected,type):

```
new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\"+ctidSelected+"\\"+type)).Directory.Create();
```

But the directory created is "CopyFiles\1000" and not "CopyFiles\1000\type1" where ctidSelected = 1000 and type = type1

Comment: First put it into a string, **use the debugger** to examine the contents of the string. ***Use the debugger***. It is there for this kind of thing.

Comment: `Directory` returns the directory part of the path, in your case the path is "CopyFiles\1000\type1" and the directory "CopyFiles\1000".

Comment: FileInfo.Directory "Gets an instance of the parent directory."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `Directory.CreateDirectory` instead of getting the parent directory and create that one:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CopyFiles"), ctidSelected, type));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string ctidSelected= "1000";
string type = "type1";

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\"+ctidSelected+"\\"+type));
```

Comment: `#include system.io`?